# Implementing Semantic Versioning with Nuget version constraints

Tags: .net, nuget, semantic-versioning

Is there a shorthand for implementing semver using version constraints in packages.config?

For example, if my application references version 1.2.3 of a package the correct `allowedVersions` attribute would be `[1.2,2)` or `[1.2.3,2)` the latter being a slight optimization perhaps.  Currently I have to manage the value of the `allowedVersions` explicitly and manually which having read https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning I believe is the only option.

Ideally there would be a token, e.g. `allowedVersions ="{semver}"`, that would implement this for me automatically as I upgrade my package refs.

Comment: This sounds like a feature request you should present to the appropriate Nuget project on GitHub: https://github.com/search?q=Nuget